# How to extract string from javascript code?

Tags: python, node.js

https://www2.newegg.com/Common/Ajax/Navigation.aspx?callback=Web.Template.RolloverMenu2015.JsonpCallBack

The following is the output from the above URL. I want to extract the string in the argument of `Web.Template.RolloverMenu2015.JsonpCallBack()`. Notice there are escapes. I am not sure what is the best way to handle a string with escapes. Does anybody know what is the best way to extract the original string (i.e, in the unescaped from) from the output from that URL (in python and in nodejs)? Thanks.

```
Web.Template.RolloverMenu2015.JsonpCallBack("<nav class=\"btn...
```

Comment: with or without the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP is just JSON, but wrapped in a function call so that it can be treated like an HTML `<script>`. If you strip off everything up to the first paren (`Web.Template.RolloverMenu2015.JsonpCallBack(`), then also remove the last paren, you should be able to proceed just as you would with regular JSON, using something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

The standard `json.loads()` knows all about how to handle all of the escaped characters and the rest of JSON syntax.